# Appengine request cost estimate

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an appengine app that allows paying customers to export their data in CSV for further analysis (BI and such). They are paying a monthly fee and I want to estimate how much would cost such an export. Does appengine provide APIs to compute the cost of a request? If not, is there any other way to compute it?

Thanks,
Cristian.

Comment: Probably belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to look at exactly what app engine resources you'd be using. There's a per-unit cost table available [HERE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing175).